# Use bind to chain continuous functions

Tags: .net, f#, functional-programming, monads, pipeline

[Result type](https://github.com/fsharp/fslang-design/blob/master/FSharp-4.1/FS-1004-result-type.md) is a new feature in F# 4.1:

```
type Result<'T,'TError> = 
| Ok of 'T
| Error of 'TError

bind : ('T -> Result<'U, 'TError>) -> Result<'T, 'TError> -> Result<'U, 'TError>
```

How can I use `Result.bind` function to chain continuous functions for the example below?

Assuming I want to save some data to a file. If it succeeds, it should return the saved data, or error string if it fails:

Firstly, I try to create a directory using **either**  `createDirectory` **or** `createDirectory2`. Then, I attempt to create a file using **both** `createFile` **and** `getPermissionType` functions. Finally, I save the data to the file.

```
let init data directoryPath =
    (match createDirectory directoryPath with
    | Ok directory -> Ok directory
    | Error err1 ->
        match createDirectory2 directoryPath with
        | Ok directory -> Ok directory
        | Error err2 -> Error (err1 + "; " + err2))
    |> function
       | Ok directory ->
             match (createFile directory directoryPath), (getPermissionType directory) with
             | Ok filePath, Ok permissionType ->
                 Ok (saveData data directory filePath permissionType)
             | Error err1, Ok _ -> Error err1
             | Ok _, Error err2 -> Error err2
             | Error err1, Error err2 -> Error (err1 + "; " + err2)
       | Error err -> err
```

Comment: Railway oriented programming is explained here: https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/recipe-part2

Comment: I personally find `Result<>` a bit problematic to use with ROP, the reason being that here's no homogenus error type. While I can make no claim on being near Scott in terms of writing perhaps you can find some of value here: https://gist.github.com/mrange/1d2f3a26ca039588726fd3bd43cc8df3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure if the F# library functions for `Result` implement all you need here - the `bind` operation lets you sequentially compose multiple operations and it stops at the first error.

In your case, you want to run one of two possible functions and then you want to do two operations and collect the errors they generate. To do this, you'd probably need to define more `Result` functions. Something like this does the trick (I changed the code to collect *lists* of errors):

```
module Result = 
  let either f1 f2 = 
    match f1 () with
    | Ok res -> Ok res
    | Error e1 -> 
        match f2 () with
        | OK res -> Ok res
        | Error e2 -> (e1 @ e2)
  let both res1 res2 = 
    match res1, res2 with
    | Ok r1, Ok r2 -> Ok (r1, r2)
    | Error e1, Error e2 -> Error (e1 @ e2)
    | Error e, _ | _, Error e -> Error e
```

Now you can express your logic as follows:

```
let init data directoryPath =
  Result.either 
    (fun () -> createDirectory directoryPath)
    (fun () -> createDirectory2 directoryPath)
  |> Result.bind (fun directory ->
      Result.both (createFile directory directoryPath) (getPermissionType directory)) 
  |> Result.map (fun (filePath, permissionType) ->
      saveData data directory filePath permissionType))
```